How to split norm square of two matrices' summation
It is known that for any two matrix $A,B$ (not necessarily square), we have $$\forall \alpha >0, \|A+B \|_F^2 \leq (1+\alpha)\|A \|_F^2 +(1+\alpha^{-1}) \| B \|_F^2.$$
This is about the Frobenius norm. Now I want to know how can we upper-bound similar thing with respect to 1-norm: $ \|A+B \|_1^2$? In our case, we only have interest in square $A,B$, where "1-norm" is simply the maximum absolute column sum of the matrix.
BTW, I believe the answer should be yes.

What is the 1-norm of a matrix? The 1-norm of the flattened matrix (a vector)?

@msantama Thanks for the question. It is simply the maximum absolute column sum of the matrix, I've added this part to the OP.

It’s still a little ambiguous. Do you mean $\max_j \sum_i \left| x_{ij} \right|$ or $\max_j \left| \sum_i x_{ij} \right|$?

@msantama It is the former one. You can check some examples on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#p_=1,%E2%88%9E

By triangle inequality,
$$\|A+B\|_1^2\leq(\|A\|_1+\|B\|_1)^2=\|A\|_1^2+\|B\|_1^2+2\|A\|_1\|B\|_1.$$
By AM-GM inequality, for any $\alpha>0$
$$2\|A\|_1\|B\|_1=2\big(\alpha^{1/2}\|A\|_1\big)\big(\alpha^{-1/2}\|B\|_1\big)\leq\alpha\|A\|_1^2+\alpha^{-1}\|B\|_1^2.$$
Combining these two bounds gives
$$\|A+B\|_1^2\leq(1+\alpha)\|A\|_1^2+(1+\alpha^{-1})\|B\|_1^2.$$

May I further ask if this trick can be applied to any (matrix) norm?

@WilliamZheng Yes, I believe the same bound holds for any norm (not only matrix norm)
